# Can't get my riding mower to start, Craftsman LT1000

Tags: starting, lawnmower

Ok, so here's the full timeline on what's happened.  About a week or 2 ago I got a mower from a guy I know who wasn't using it.  It's an 18HP Craftsman LT1000.  The only issue he told me about is that the blade is a little bent in one spot and the battery needs to be jumped before it's used each time.  So, it obviously needs a new battery.  I tried it out after he dropped it off and it seemed to be working well.  I did notice that it needed more oil though.  I filled it until the stick said it was full and then put it away for the night.

When I took it back out I started it up, there was a giant ball of smoke, and then it shut down.  I checked the oil again and saw that it was now saying that it was way over filled.  So, I drained off the excess oil.

Now I still can't get it started.  While I have it being jumped I can see something spinning in the engine but it never actually starts up, just keeps spinning.  I'm at a loss for what to do to get it up and running.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this the 18 HP Briggs and Stratton oposed TWIN IC motor? Have you pulled the plugs to see if they are wet (engine flooded)?

Comment: go back to basics - spark, fuel, compression.  Pull the plugs, make sure they are clean.  Make sure they are sparking.  Dump some fuel in the carb to see if that can kick it over for a few seconds.  If its sparking, and getting fuel, but still not starting, check the compression.

Comment: Yes, this is the 18 HP B&S Engine.

Comment: How can I check to see if it's sparking?

Comment: pull the plug, touch the body of the plug to the block (or use a wire with 2 clips, clip one end to the block and other to the threads of the spark plug), then try to start it and watch the plug for spark.

Comment: On any flat mounted V-Twin, storing with the cylinder heads even slightly downhill will result in a lot of smoke on startup. Once you get the starting situation sorted out, store it level or with the heads (usually the nose of the tractor) pointed uphill.